How to get socket file descriptor when using eBPF to trace TLS traffic in OpenSSL
I can successfully use eBPF to trace TLS traffic when using OpenSSL v1.1.1. Kernel is 5.15.0-102-generic
I want to get the fd of this SSL connection in order to know the end point of TLS traffic. Seems there are 2 options. One option is to create partially of struct ssl_st and struct bio_st to find the field num in bio_st. Second option is to use offset to get field num from those 2 structs.
I tried both options and they all return fd: 5 to me in different machines or containers. I use the following part of code to test, apparently, 5 is not a valid socket.
struct stat statbuf;
if (fstat(fd, &statbuf) == -1) {
    perror("fstat failed");
} else {
    if (S_ISSOCK(statbuf.st_mode)) {
        printf("fd %d is a socket.\n", fd);
    } else {
        printf("fd %d is not a socket.\n", fd);
    }
}

The test I did is using curl to a https website. It also can trace other TLS traffic, i.e. upgrade vscode, etc. All traffics return fd:5
wget-1393473 [002] d...1 320246.200736: bpf_trace_printk: uprobe/SSL_write wbio_num is 5
wget-1393473 [002] d...1 320247.743324: bpf_trace_printk: uprobe/SSL_read rbio_num is 5

I tried with getsockname and getpeername with fd:5, and I got the following error
getsockname() failed: Socket operation on non-socket
getpeername() failed: Socket operation on non-socket

The print API looks like
void print_socket_details(int fd) {
    struct sockaddr_in localaddr;
    socklen_t localaddrlen;
    if (getsockname(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&localaddr, &localaddrlen) == 0) {
        printf("Local IP address: %s\n", inet_ntoa(localaddr.sin_addr));
        printf("Local port: %d\n", ntohs(localaddr.sin_port));
    } else {
        perror("getsockname() failed");
    }
    
    struct sockaddr_in peeraddr;
    socklen_t peeraddrlen;
    if (getpeername(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&peeraddr, &peeraddrlen) == 0) {
        printf("Remote IP address: %s\n", inet_ntoa(peeraddr.sin_addr));
        printf("Remote port: %d\n", ntohs(peeraddr.sin_port));
    } else {
        perror("getpeername() failed");
    }
}

Does anyone have an idea how to get the real fd from ssl_read/ssl_write? Did I miss anything?
Thanks in advance!

That is the real fd. fstat only works on things that are in the filesystem (i.e. have an inode) which a named Unix-domain socket does, but not an Internet (IPv4 or IPv6) socket. To get the remote endpoint of an Internet socket (if/while connected) use getpeername.

Thanks for the quick reply Dave! However, I tried with using getsockname() and getpeername() they both won't work with fd:5. I got the following error
getsockname() failed: Socket operation on non-socket
getpeername() failed: Socket operation on non-socket
